# Little sparks on laptop with external monitors when touched

Tags: usb, laptop, hdmi

I have a Zenbook laptop, which usually is connected to two external monitors, one through HDMI and another through USB 3.0 external graphic card. The problem is whenever I have these two monitors connected, every now and then when I touch my laptop little sparks happen. I have two questions.

1. Will this harm my laptop or its battery?
2. Should I connect my laptop to earth using a wire for it to be discharged of electric charge?

Comment: There is a certain level of static electricity around, more in dry areas, less in humid areas. Small sparks do not harm things. I usually touch the desk or surface near the computer and this dissipates static electricity.  No need to ground your laptop with a wire.

Comment: The only issue from *static* might be when inserting or removing a device, particularly cards such as XD. Touch the laptop with one hand while inserting the card with the other to keep the potentials close. However, if you mean anything *other* than static DC, you've got an issue!